# Rust: invoking rustc using subprocess shell

Tags: shell, rust, subprocess

So here is the problem: I want to call a rust compiler on a piece of code. Instead of spewing warnings though stderr, it outputs a help page on stdout and exits. What is wrong with this?

```
let compilation = subprocess::Exec::shell("rustc")
.arg("-o").arg("binary")
.arg("-O").arg(path)
.stderr(subprocess::Redirection::Merge)
.capture().unwrap();

let compilationpassed = compilation.success();
let compilationlog = compilation.stdout_str();
```

Comment: I don't know the library you use but just in case you're not aware, you can do this quite simply with the standard lib (`process::Command`).

Comment: Ah gomen. I am using subprocess crate. Could you show me how to do it with std? Please?

Comment: I have [this example](https://github.com/Canop/bacon/blob/main/src/executor.rs#L38) where the output of rust compilation is stored for analysis but it's quite a complex example with parallelism and interruptions. You may find the `process::Command` doc more helpful for an introduction.

Comment: And you are absolutely right.  process::Command does all I need.

Comment: If you have a fixed and elegant code, I suggest you paste it as an answer with explanation and comments. Such example may help later users having a similar problem.

Comment: The concrete problem with your code is that `Exec::shell()` is for when you have a full command line, e.g. `Exec::shell("rustc -o bla")`. You should use `Exec::cmd("rustc")` instead.

Comment: Exec::cmd does not solve it tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a specific crate to launch a process, the standard [`process::Command`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html) contains what you need.

You seem to want to launch rustc then inherit stdin and/or stdout.

That would be this:

```
std::process::Command::new("rustc")
    .arg("-o").arg("binary")
    .arg("-O").arg(path)
    .spawn()
    .expect("ls command failed to start")
    .wait(); // you should better handle the result here
```

If you want to discard stderr or stdout you may change the behaviour with the homonym functions [`stderr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.stderr) and [`stdout`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.stdout).